# How to disable all implicit conversion of primitive types?

Tags: scala, numbers, implicit-conversion

Scala seems to behave like Java when it comes to the magic conversion of primitives:

```
val a: Int = 1
val b: Double = 2.3
println(a + b) // 3.3 
println(Math.max(a, b)) // 2.3
```

More often than not, this has been a source of bugs in my code. Is there a way to disable these implicit conversions so that my example give a compilation warnning/error? I would really rather have to write

```
print(a.toDouble + b)
println(Math.max(a.toDouble, b))
```

every single time I need such conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [WartRemover](https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover). A wart like that isn't built-in, but could be written (see "Writing Wart Rules" in README). Though now that I think, it's probably more work than I thought initially.

`scalac` also has `-Ywarn-numeric-widen` option (together with `-Xfatal-warnings` to turn the warnings to errors), but I don't know if there are any cases not covered by it.

Comment: You may also want `-Yno-predef` to disable some implicits. More generally, see http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/04/11/scalac-flags.html

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This article on scalac-flags is golden <3